# Matlab: Element by element selection without loops

Tags: matlab, selection, element, nested-loops

I have one big matrix of for example 3000X300. And I need to select each element and do several calculations with it. I looked into using the array fun function but because the output of my program is not one value this is not possible. 
It works fine now with the loops but it has to preform much faster, so i want to remove the for loop.

Maybe i'll try to be more specific: Each value of the big matrix has to give me an answer of 4 different matrices with the size of 4X6020..

So i don't know if this is possible making this vectorized... 
Maybe somebody has other suggestions to make it faster?

greetings,

Comment: Could you post a short example, perhaps of what you do in your loop so that I can get an idea of the format of the output? Such as `for x=1:3000; for y=1:300; out(x,y,:,:) = func1(in(x,y)); end; end;` Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrayfun` and set `uniformoutput` to `false`. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html).